# Are gas/petrol stations in Ireland typically "pump your own gas/petrol"?

Tags: automobiles, ireland

In past trips to Ireland, I remember petrol stations being full-service like the US states of Oregon and New Jersey. I also remember a few self-service stations.  But I don't recall which was more prevalent and I am sure its changed since I last visited.

But what kind of service is typically found nowadays in Ireland?

And if it is self-service, are they typically pay at the pump with credit card?

Comment: One other thing you should be aware of is that the green handle is petrol and the black handle is diesel. This is the reverse of the US.

Comment: @Jay Cummins I suspect the answer will depend on whether you’re in the city/on the motorway or in rural areas. In the former you can expect to find more self-service/pay at pump petrol stations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Service:** 
Petrol stations in Ireland are self-service.

Will it be possible to find somewhere where the service is offered? Probably.

Anecdotally I haven't been anywhere that does that in the last 20 years (and it was very rare then).

Even then the situation you're describing is quite different. In places like New Jersey, AFAIK it's *required* that an employee operate the pump while when serviced stations existed in Ireland it was an offered service rather than a required one.

**Payment:**
Fill your tank then go into the shop to pay (park away from the pump first if you're especially polite).

Prepay may be required in some 24hr stations after a certain time (eg. midnight), though even then it's not very common. Where this exists, it's normally either prepay with card at the pump or at a service window at the shop. Very, very occasionally a station will have one of their pumps which is prepay 24hrs (with other pumps working as normal).

Comment: I just returned after 2 weeks and I can confirm that it is self-service. 2 stations were fill first, pay inside.  The 3rd (near the dublin airport) had the option to pay at the pump.